# Is there an override field for event times?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

We've designed a touchscreen "app" which is essentially just a webserver and set of html files running on a machine. However, the machines these apps run on are frequently offline - they store their actions and when back online send them to our server as a batch. We'd like to have google analytics for tracking users and their actions, including event times during the day. Is there any way to override the event time when posting to google analytics to force it to be the time our service has recorded for the event, rather than the time analytics received the event? I looked through the documentation but didn't see any way to override that. I suppose I could use a custom field(?) but it would be far more convenient if there was some kind of override.

Thanks

Comment: as long as its not greater than four hours ago you can use this https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#qt

Comment: OK, I'd seen that, and was hoping for something a bit more flexible/precise. For things like trade shows etc the machines can be offline for a number of hours, or even days. Maybe that will get us close enough, or we can work around it. Thanks!

Comment: Nope that is the best there is. It is a known issue